# Does git log output CRLF for newlines if core.autocrlf is true?

Tags: git

I'm trying to store info for the last 10 commits in a text file.  I'm doing

```
git log -10 --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short > info.txt
```

The line endings aren't showing up in Notepad.  All the commits are listed on one line.  If I open it in Wordpad instead, the commits are on separate lines, which is what I want. This leads me to believe that each line has only a LF and not a CRLF.

`git config --global core.autocrlf` is `true`; shouldn't this affect the output of `git log` as well?  `git config core.autocrlf` is also `true`.

I'm trying this from a command prompt (`cmd`).

Is there a solution for this?  I'd rather not have to use Wordpad to view the file output; it loads slower than Notepad.

Comment: Have you tried it? I think git will always use `LF` as default line separator character. Maybe you should give another editor, e.g. [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), a try. Windows' Notepad is quite limited in functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trying [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) instead of regular vanilla Windows notepad?  It's very lightweight, loads fast, and is way more customizable and has more features than notepad.  It's actually used as the default editor for one of the Git tools for Windows, but I can't remember which one...maybe it was GitHub for Windows or just plain msysgit?

Comment: I switched to it.  It came with an installer that replaced Windows Notepad.  It loads fast!  Thanks!